# What's the best way to extract baby snot?

Tags: infant, health

Our baby currently has a cold which means her nose is streaming with snot.
She is quite unhappy with us wiping it away with a tissue every few minutes. I can imagine her upper lip is getting quite sore.

What is the best, most comfortable, way to clear this snot away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some sort of basic [nasal aspirator](http://www.babycenter.com/0_how-to-use-a-bulb-syringe-or-nasal-aspirator-to-clear-a-stuf_482.bc) is what you are looking for.  The one pictured in that article is very similar to the one that our hospital gave us as part of the newborn care package.

However, I have heard great things about [Nosefrida's appropriately-named 'The Snotsucker'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00171WXII).  It seems to address the issues we've had using the simple bulb, as it is much easier to clean, and apparently does not require sticking it up the child's nostril (our son absolutely hated that part).

Comment: We used to call the bulb thing the brain sucker based on the reaction kids have when you use it. As far as they know, they think you're sucking their brains out and will fight you to the death when they see it. That said, it works.

Comment: We use the Nosefrida for our twins and it's much better than the bulb-style sucker we used for the first child. Can't say they enjoy it any better, but it is much more effective and easy to clean.

Comment: My youngest didn't mind it at first, since he knew it made him feel better and was quiet when we used it.  Now he is in a cranky phase and anything you get near to use it you can't hold him still.

Comment: Found we already had one at home. I used to thing it was something my partner bought for the kitchen. It is amazing how much snot it gets out!

Comment: Nosefrida FTW. They’re amazing.

Answer (score 5):

My wife uses a combination of a nasal aspirator with a combination of nasal saline.  Works like a charm with our baby.  Just put the saline in, wait a few seconds, then suck.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the bulb aspirator wasn't strong enough.  We used an [electric aspirator](http://www.target.com/p/NasalClear-Nasal-Aspirator-BR140/-/A-10387113).  They run around $20, so it is much more expensive than the bulb-style aspirator, but it worked much better.  It makes a pretty loud motor noise, but that actually distracts our baby and stops her from crying.

Comment: Probably a great help, but the concept of hooking an electric pump up to an infants nose scares me.

Comment: I was surprised at first that they would even sell something like that, but I tried it out on my hand, and the suction didn't seem strong enough to be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The manual aspirators didn't work at all for us, so we switched to a vacuum cleaner attached model.

Yes it sounds horrible but they are perfectly safe.

I only know German models so here is one model with an English description on [eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NASAL-ASPIRATOR-Angel-Vac-doctors-recommended-/140413518703).

From our experience they work very well but our daughter didn't like it at all but it was the only way to clear the nose and give her a good night's sleep.

Comment: Wait, like an actual vacuum cleaner?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Everybody I told about this had the same reaction. The constant suction really helps. It is also safety certified.

Comment: Where does it say they are safe?

Answer (score 1):

Hold her near a sink with running water and extract the snot with wet fingers. This is especially useful before sleep time as it will ease her falling asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Nosefrida FTW

[http://www.amazon.com/Nosefrida-The-Snotsucker-Nasal-Aspirator/dp/B00171WXII](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00171WXII)

I know sucking snot seems gross, but it really provides you a lot of control.  Plus there's a sponge in there protecting you from actually tasting baby snot (I'm sure we've all done worse as parents).

Answer (score 0):

Squeeze the air out of a bulb of a "blue bulb syringe" to create a vacuum, then gently insert the rubber tip into one nostril. Another apparatus for this is a "nasal aspirator", a catheter-type device that uses the parent's sucking and a reservoir for mucus, which is more controlled.

Comment: My baby is 8 years old now. :-)